# Domain of $f(x)=\sqrt{\sqrt{\sin x}+\sqrt{\cos x}-1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, inequality

Find Domain of $f(x)=\sqrt{\sqrt{\sin x}+\sqrt{\cos x}-1}$

My try:

First of all $x$ belongs to First quadrant

Also  $$\sqrt{\sin x}+\sqrt{\cos x}-1 \ge 0$$  Squaring both sides we get

$$\sin x+\cos x+2\sqrt{\sin x\cos x} \ge 1$$

Any clue here?

Comment: Hint: What is the domain of $\sqrt x$ and when do $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ produce values outside that domain? Apply this logic again to the final square root.

Comment: "$x$ belongs to first quadrant" What do you mean by this? Do you mean that all points $(x,f(x))$ are in the first quadrant? (this is not true)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By periodicity, we can restrict ourselves to $[0, 2\pi[$. As you've noticed, $x$ must be in $X:=[0, \pi/2]$.

One method to continue is to notice that, for $a$ in $[0,1]$, we have $\sqrt{a} \geq a$, therefore for $x$ in $X$ we have $$\sqrt{\sin(x)} + \sqrt{\cos(x)} \geq \sin(x) + \cos(x)$$

It is then easy to check that $\sin(x) + \cos(x) \geq 1$ for $x$ in $X$, for example by squaring. So, the domain of $f$ is $X$.

Comment: You may conclude faster by noting $\sqrt a \ge a^2$.  For the approach +1 anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: you must solve $$\sin(x)\geq 0$$ and $$\cos(x)\geq 0$$ and $$\sqrt{\sin(x)}+\sqrt{\cos(x)}-1\geq 0$$

Answer (score 2):

For
$f(x)=\sqrt{\sqrt{\sin x}+\sqrt{\cos x}-1}$,
you first of all have to
restrict $x$ to the reals.

Then,
since $\sin$ and $\cos$
are periodic
with period $2\pi$,
you can restrict $x \in [0, 2 \pi)$.
Any restrictions there
are replicated in
$[2k\pi, 2(k+1)\pi)$.

Since you need
$\sin(x) \ge 0$,
this gives
$x \in [0, \pi]$.

Since you need
$\cos(x) \ge 0$,
this gives
$x \in [0, \pi/2]\cup [3\pi/2, 2\pi)$.

Combining these gives
$x \in [0, \pi/2]$.

Finally,
you want 
$\sqrt{\sin x}+\sqrt{\cos x}-1
\ge 0$.

If $f(x)
= \sqrt{\sin x}+\sqrt{\cos x}-1
$,
then
$f(x) = f(\pi/2-x)$,
so we only need to look at
$x \in [0, \pi/4]$.

$f(0) = 0$,
$f(\pi/4)
=\sqrt{2}-1
\gt 0$.

$\begin{array}\\
f'(x)
&=\frac12 \cos(x) \sin^{-1/2}(x)-\frac12 \sin(x) \cos^{-1/2}(x)\\
&=\frac12 \dfrac{\cos^{3/2}(x)- \sin^{3/2}(x)}{\sin^{1/2}(x) \cos^{1/2}(x)}\\
\end{array}
$

and since
$\cos(x) > \sin(x)$
for
$x \in [0, \pi/4)$,
$f'(x) > 0$ for
$0 \le x \lt \pi/4$
so $f(x)
\ge 0$
for
$0 \le x \le \pi/2$
with equality only at
$x=0$
and
$x = \pi/2$.

Answer (score 0):

You need $\sqrt{\sin(x)}+\sqrt{\sin(\dfrac{\pi}{2}-x)}\ge 1$. Looking at the graphics you can see that the domain is 
$$\left([0,\dfrac{\pi}{2}]\cup[2\pi,2\pi+\dfrac{\pi}{2}\cup\cdots\right)\cup\left([-2\pi,-2\pi+\dfrac{\pi}{2}]\cup[-4\pi,4\pi+\dfrac{\pi}{2}]\cup\cdots\right)$$ Finally the domain is the union for all $k\in\mathbb Z$ of the intervals
$$\left[2k\pi,2k\pi+\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right]$$